# Multiple rendering <a> tag when pseudo ::before is applied

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have the following structure of html structure:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also i have css file:

```
a[href*='facebook.com/']:before {
    content: "\ea90";
}
```

The problem is that i find duplications of `a` tag in generated DOM stucture, and these elements are also shown on page. What did i miss?

Rendered html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
        <a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank"></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: we don't write `a` tag like this ...

Comment: Can you post what your rendered DOM structure looks like?

Comment: The anchor needs a closing tag to work properly: `<a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank"></a>`

Comment: @LGSon Thank you very much! It helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You must close your anchor tag. You would want to change your code to look like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://facebook.com/" target="_blank"/>example text</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you fill in anything where I wrote "example text" it will put a label for that list item. Hope this helps!